# Django Haystack - are facets limited to 10?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I'm indexing a list of products and each product has a list of categories. Categories are about 1000.

In the search page I would like to list **all** the categories which have more than 1 result.

---

I'm collecting facets with:

```
results.facet_counts()
```

**Unfortunately this just returns the top 10 categories!**

I can't seem to find a way to have it return more.

---

I'm using the latest version of **Haystack** and **ElasticSearch**.

---

Hope someone can help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify in your json query the size of your facet, which is the number of entries you will get back:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {  }
    },
    "facets" : {
        "tag" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "tag",
                "size" : 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to configure a high value if you want to have back all the entries.
Not sure how you can add this parameter with the library you're using. Hope the answer will be useful anyway.

Comment: Hi I'm not sure if the answer is helpful yet. I'm trying to investigate how the library is communicating with ElasticSearch. Maybe there are API logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `get_queryset()` method of your custom `FacetedSearchView` as:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    options = {"size": 0} #unlimited results, use with caution
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    for field in self.facet_fields:
        qs = qs.facet(field, **options)
    return qs
```

You can also define a global setting `ELASTIC_FACET_SIZE` and use that instead.

```py
from settings import ELASTIC_FACET_SIZE 

def get_queryset(self):
    options = {"size": ELASTIC_FACET_SIZE} #unlimited results, use with caution
    qs = super().get_queryset()
    for field in self.facet_fields:
        qs = qs.facet(field, **options)
    return qs
```

This way you won't have to mess with the haystack package source code

Answer (score 0):

Now they are limited to 100, see https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/658